# Determine UIView container size without autoresizing

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I am using Auto Layout in iOS 7 programmatically. I have a dynamic view component, which acts as a container for multiple subviews. It is not known how many subviews the container is supposed to hold, only that the view will be equal in width to it's subviews and dynamic in height, depending on how many subviews there will be.

= ContainerView's bounds

```
 =======
 = SV1 =
 = SV2 =
 = SVn =
 = ... =
 =======
```

Since I am doing all Autolayout programmatically I need a way to tell the container view that it is supposed to be CGSize x big. How can I do this with Autolayout and no Autoresizing?

Comment: Can't you just set a constraint that makes your view's width equal to the container view's width?

Comment: That might very well work for the width. I have edited my original question to clarify my issue.

Comment: Is there is a reason to not set your height constraint to total height of the subviews?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work as long as all your subviews specify a valid vertical size in `-intrinsicContentSize` (Apple’s controls do this by default, for example.) Then, pin the tops and bottoms of the subviews to each other, the top of SV1 to the top of the container, and the bottom of SVn to the bottom of the container. Then the container will always be the height of the views it contains.

Answer (score 0):

After all, I set the multiplier in NSLayoutConstraint's -constraintWithItem:... to the number of items I expected in the view. I had to set up some other constraints, but at least it works like I imagined. I was still hoping for a less code-prone solution to my problem (comparable to just set the autoresizingmask, a one-liner).